# Burninate [live-issue]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

In creating the [tuleap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuleap) tag and updating questions to include it, I noticed a number of these questions were tagged with [live-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live-issue).

- The tag has no wiki entry
- Only 28 questions are tagged with it

  - Of these, 13 were by one (low-rep) user on Tuleap questions.  I don't see how the tag makes sense in those, but I don't know Tuleap well.
  - The other 15 are a smattering of tags, including XCode, Visual Studio, JavaScript, Java, and Excel.

I think some people are interpreting it as "having an issue in a live environment", but that's pretty vague itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[live-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live-issue) is now dead.

[image]