# To [live] is to die

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We apparently have a [live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live) (x1221) tag. This seems to mean that either:

- Something is happening, or being broadcast, in real-time
- Something about a Microsoft API
- jQuery's `.live()` (deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed from jQuery 1.9)
- Live (auto-updating) search.
- Or a myriad of other unrelated things

A random sampling of questions from the first page:

- [Broadcasting live video on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004390/broadcasting-live-video-on-facebook)
- [Live search with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933172/live-search-with-ajax)
- [Asus Xtion Pro Live and PyOpenni RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892546/asus-xtion-pro-live-and-pyopenni-rgb)
- [Azure Live Streaming RTMP with CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872526/azure-live-streaming-rtmp-with-cdn)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344509/microsoft-live-api-synchronize-event-calendars-with-push
- [jQuery .live() for multiple selectors - how to unbind event from one of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981472/jquery-live-for-multiple-selectors-how-to-unbind-event-from-one-of-them)

And so on and so forth. This tag means nothing. I think we should go through the questions looking for closure-targets, then burninate it.

Thoughts?

Comment: I remember that there was one burnination request before...

Comment: @Braiam I looked for something, the closest I could find was http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271115/burninate-live-issue?s=2|2.5193

Comment: Do you need help from the Close vote room?

Comment: It is being abused by low rep users that haven't learned yet how to tag properly.  [jquery][live] makes a lot of sense.  But they make mistakes like [windows][live] and [live][streaming] instead of [windows-live] and [live-streaming].  Lots of editing to do, I propose we get rid of low rep users instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: Whoever made that tag invited such abuse. Should have been [jquery-live] from the beginning. If it actually merits its own tag, which I don't know. ([Burninate the \[user\]! With fire!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268187/burninate-the-user-with-fire) was a different request ;-))

Comment: The tag wiki states that it is for the jQuery. Is there a way to rename this tag?

Comment: @jakekimds Renaming wouldn't be enough - we'd have to remove it from all the questions that *aren't* jQuery first.

Comment: If we are to edit these post should we remove the tag if the question does not have [tag:jquery] taged to it?

Answer (score 4):

There are actually [677 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live+-jquery) with the [live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/live) tag but not the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) one. If we all do a couple of edits, it should go away *rather* quickly. :-)

I will go first and edit/flag/improve/un-tag the 10 most recent. Join me in this task, and we'll be able to rename the thing!

Comment: If a question should be closed, _keep the tag in_ so the SO Close Vote Review room can burninate using the tag.

Comment: Duly noted! @KevinBrown

Comment: Please, since you're below 2k rep, fix all of the problems in the question while you're editing the tags.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I appreciate your tip Mike; sadly, it's been a few years since then!

Comment: Ha! I didn't even read the date. Someone edited the page and it showed up on the front. Well, thanks for effort ;).